# How do I delete elements with >2 columns in a list?

Tags: r

I am learning to scrape websites using R. I have managed to scrape a website with multiple tables on a single page. When I create a html table I am shown a list with 498 elements (each referring to the tables on the page).

I only want to keep the elements of this list that have 2 columns.

The code I have used is:

```
lineup <- remDr$findElement(using= 'class', 'lineup_table_group')

lineup_html <- lineup$getPageSource()
lineuppage <- read_html(lineup_html %>% unlist())
lineupdata <- html_table(lineuppage)
lineupdata
```

the data I want are the elements which show each table in long format that look like this:

| X1 | X2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10:15 |
| B | 12:00 |

But R also scrapes the tables in wide format, which look like this:

**X**

```
| A | 10:15 | B | 12:00 |
```

I don't know how to stop R from scraping the tables in wide format as well. I also don't know how to delete these "wide" elements from within the list.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the wide format also in the web that you scrap? afaik the library should parse as written in the HTML

Comment: Yes it is. There are 3 tables side by side on each row on the page. so it is scraping those three together, and then all three of these separately